# How to implement shell input redirecting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How to write a shell that collect content from file and input to command?
it would look like:  $ command < inputfile
I don't know how to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Do you actually want to ***write a shell***, or do you want to write a *shell script*?  What documentation have you read so far?  The most successful questions here tend to include code, expected results and actual results.  When questions state "I don't know how to start", one of the common answers is "Google".

Answer (score 1):

Using `wc` as an example:

```
$ wc < input_file > output_file
```

**Explanation**:

- `wc`: this is the command (or shell builtin) you are invoking
- `< input_file`: read input from `input_file`
- `> output_file': write output into`output_file`

Note that many commands will accept the input file name as one of its cmdline arguments (without using `<`), for example:

- `grep pattern file_name`
- `awk '{print}' file_name`
- `sed 's/hi/bye/g` file_name`

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the input file descriptor of your shell program to the inputfile.  In c, it is achieved by calling `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);` whose job is making newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary.
In Unix/Linux, every process has its own file descriptors, stored like this:

0 - Standard input (stdin)
1 - Standard output (stdout)
2 - Standard error (stderr)

So you should point the stdin descriptor to the inputfile you want to use. 
Here's how I wrote this months before:

```
void ioredirection(int type,char *addr) {
    // output append redirection using ">>"
    if (type == 2) {
        re_file = open(addr, O_APPEND | O_RDWR, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
        type--;
    }
    // output redirection using ">"
    else if (type==1) re_file = open(addr, O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
    // input redirection using "<" or "<<"
    else re_file = open(addr, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
    old_stdio = dup(type);
    dup2(re_file, type);
    close(re_file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read from input in bash script using command `read`:

**inputreader.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

**Output**

```
$ echo "Test" | bash ./inputreader.sh
Test
$ echo "Line 1" >> ./file; echo "Line 2" >> ./file
$ cat ./file | bash ./inputreader.sh
Line 1
Line 2
$ bash ./inputreader.sh < ./file 
Line 1
Line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `xargs` for that:

for example you have a file which has some list of file names.

```
cat your_file|xargs wc -l
```

`wc -l` is your command 
`cat` and `xargs` will pass each line in the file as an input to `wc -l`

so the output would be the count of lines of all the files whose names are present in the inputfile
main thing here is `xargs` will pass each and every line as an input to `wc -l`